# How to upload a group of Shapefiles into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a folder with 211 Shapefiles that I want to upload as a group into my project.

I have been looking for a way to upload all the files simultaneously, but I have failed to find one.

Is there a way to upload all these files in one go?

Comment: Have you tried drag and drop all selected files from the folder opened in the OS file explorer to the QGIS project legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open multiple files (shapefiles) and group them with e.g. source catalog name, it's very handy to use Load Them All plugin (www: http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/264-plugin-load-them-all-para-quantum-gis). Grouping option is to activate on plugins configuration tab.

[image: Grouping option]

To install & activate plugin go to:  Plugins -> Manage plugins -> search for: Load Them All -> click it on the list and select Install plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Go to view > panels and turn on "browser panel". In that panel navigate to your folder. click the top .shp file to select it, scroll to the bottom of the folder and shift + click on the last .shp to select all the files in the folder. Then drag and drop from the browser panel to the map canvas.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/using_qgis_browser.html) to get you started with the browser