# Saving all the project layers in one folder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

There is a [nice way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260067/how-to-upload-a-group-of-shapefiles-into-qgis) to upload all the layers from one folder in QGIS.
Is there  a way to download all the layers from a project and save them in a new folder?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would be via the [QGIS Python Console](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html) (`Plugins > Python Console`, then click on the `Show Editor` icon in the left console toolbar), and then entering this code, only changing the directory you wish to save the files:

```
import ogr,os
myDir = 'C:/Shapefiles/'

if os.path.exists (myDir) == False:
   print("Path does not exist")
else:
    for vLayer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        if vLayer.type()==0: #Save only shapefiles in the Layer Panel 
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vLayer, myDir + vLayer.name() + ".shp", "utf-8", vLayer.crs(),  "ESRI Shapefile")
            print(vLayer.name() + " saved successfully")
```

Just make sure that the variable `myDir` includes the folder name followed by an additional `/` (as in the example above), and that the folder exists *before* running the script. Don't use traditional Windows back slashes `\` in the path as this will fail; use forward slashes `/` as shown.

The script will only save the active (checked) shapefiles in the layer control panel (ignoring other file formats).

Comment: Love it, Thanks 15Step! Just had to make a small change to make it work for me. The last line changed to : print (" saved successfully", vLayer.name())

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but it did not work for me. I get the following: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2
    myDir = 'C:\Shapefiles\'
                           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string litera